# How to end a button process and proceed with a button process using multiple button UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, button, uialertview

As the title says,

I am having trouble using `if` statements for multiple `UIAlertViews`. I want my program to press a button but before initiating what the button will do a confirmation box will pop up saying would you like to proceed with a `YES` or `NO`. `NO` should cancel the initiation and `YES` should just proceed.

Please help!!

Comment: Perhaps some relevant code snippets would help illustrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate to `alertView` as well as tag

```
yourAlertView.delegate = self;
yourAlertView.tag = 108;

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag==108)
    {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
               //Your actions
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can differentiate alertView with tags. Cancel button index is always 0

Comment: Sorry i'm actually noob at this but what does it mean to set delegate to alertview? Do i define that on the appDelegate.m and .h files?

Comment: You can set alertView Delegate as follows


@interface ALBaseViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>

Implement the following where you want

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Continue with" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Action1", nil];
    alertView.tag = 108;
    [alertView show];